# How do I write a lattice graph (say a square lattice) in boost C++ library?

Tags: c++, boost

Most examples in the boost-library shows me how to create a graph in boost by adding vertices and edges one by one. 
If I have to create a boost graph representing a general lattice (or say a square lattice with periodic boundary conditions), how do I go about doing that ?

How do I make an edge between vertices in a for loop ?

Comment: Is using boost important?

Comment: I can get things working without boost. But boost is needed for compatibility with remaining codes.

Comment: I guess you'd code the period as a finite graph, representing infinite part. You could edit your question and show what you can do so far, and what you would like to be able to do.